# Properly (and easily ?) initiate a Spring MVC Project

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

What's the best method to initiate a new Spring Project ?

Initiating Spring project is a lot of pain with various xml and db configuration.

Is there an "official" repository with complete sample project, as MVC with db access and so ?

Spring Boot may also be the solution, but some point still not clear to me :

- How to add external components (such as Quartz) without creating some xml config ? (No such xml in Boot apparently)
- Is a Spring Boot builded app is production-proof ?

Comment: You can download the Spring Suite tools to easily get started.  It provides facilities to create a Spring MVC or Boot project with all the boiler plate.

Comment: The Spring website (spring.io) is build using Spring Boot. To create a starter project use [Spring Initializer](http://start.spring.io/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As writen in the comments http://start.spring.io/ is the best way to start Spring boot project(STS has integration for it).

If you want to use something that is not supported by Spring Boot you can init spring beans the same way you do it in xml, just use java configuration. See this for example: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_java_based_configuration.htm

Also useing xml is still available. You can add `@ImportResource` on your Configuration class

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@Configuration
@ImportResource({"classpath*:applicationContext.xml"})
```